# How to skip define type on multiple generics class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, optional-parameters

I have a class with multiple generic properties defined like this:

```
export class MainClass<
    A = string,
    B = number,
    C = boolean> {
    propA: A
    propB: B
    propC: C
}
```

It works fine if I fully define 3 types:

```
let mainClass = new MainClass<string, string, string>
```

But later I want to create a new instance and only define the 3rd type:

```
let mainClass2 = new MainClass< , ,custom-type>
```

Can we omit defining any generic (it gets the default type) and only define the ones we need?

Comment: This link may help you, [TypeScript Git](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316).

Comment: In this specific example you can reorder type parameters and define `C` to be the first one. In this case you won't need to specify the others. The idea is the same as with default function parameters

Comment: You can do this by using a pair of interfaces and a variable, following the pattern used to define `Array` in `lib.d.ts`, but in general needing to specify the arguments explicitly means that the types are not being used in the signature. This is often (but _not_ always) indicates a serious design error.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of is to create subclasses that take different type arguments.

I have illustrated your `<,,type>` example below. The type annotations are only there to show you what you (effectively) get - you don't need to add the annotations in real life here.

```
class MainClass<A = string, B = number, C = boolean> {
    propA: A
    propB: B
    propC: C
}

class MainClassB<
    C = boolean> extends MainClass<string, number, C> {
}

let example1: MainClass<string, string, string> = new MainClass<string, string, string>();

let example2: MainClass<string, number, number> = new MainClassB<number>();
```

The basic concept is that the subclass takes whatever combination of type arguments you want, and returns a class with the three properties of `MainClass`. You can create various combinations if you want to support the various one or two default situations (eliminating the combinations that can be satisfied by the original type argument order).

## Full Example

I have jammed a function in that accepts `MainClass` to show all the resulting types are structurally compatible:

```
class MainClass<A = string, B = number, C = boolean> {
    propA: A
    propB: B
    propC: C
}

class MainClassC<C> extends MainClass<string, number, C> {
}

class MainClassAC<A, C> extends MainClass<A, number, C> {
}

class MainClassBC<B, C = boolean> extends MainClass<string, B, C> {
}

function processMainClass(input: MainClass) {
    console.log(input.propA, input.propB, input.propC);
}

let a = new MainClass<string>();
processMainClass(a);

let b = new MainClassBC<number>();
processMainClass(b);

let c = new MainClassC<boolean>();
processMainClass(c);

let ab = new MainClass<string, number>();
processMainClass(ab);

let ac = new MainClassAC<string, boolean>();
processMainClass(ac);

let bc = new MainClassBC<number, boolean>();
processMainClass(bc);

let abc = new MainClass<string, number, boolean>();
processMainClass(abc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding here for people like me still landing on this question.

```
export class MainClass<
    A = string,
    B = number,
    C = boolean> {
    propA: A
    propB: B
    propC: C
}
```

Since your objective is not to create multiple classes, you could define a type alias. Its as simple as this

```
type MainClassWithDefaults<C> = MainClass<"TypeA","TypeB",C>;
let mainClass:MainClassWithDefaults<"TypeYouWantToPass"> = new MainClass()
```

If a one liner is what you are looking for, here it is.
This is still verbose, a little bit misleading, and not applicable in every case, so I wouldn't recommend this.
If you have a field in the class that is of the generic type  you want to skip (*and not a union type), you can do this.

```
let mainClass = new MainClass<MainClass["propA"], MainClass["propB"], string>()
```

`*` It won't work if the field is a union type for the following reason.

lets say the field is defined as  `propA: A | null` , the type returned by `MainClass["propA"]` will not be the default type of generic `A` but the union type `A | null`.